# Android,SQLite: Retrieving database file

Tags: android, sqlite

After creating a database file and tables in android studio.
I went to the /data/data directory(at the android device monitor) and the only directories I see are named 'con',
and not my package name.
I know there are three options:
1. I can't get the database directory because I'm working with the emulator.
2. To specify a new directory to put this file in(I don't know how).
3. To re-install android studio(I doubt it will help)

What can I do tot fix it?and what is the problem?

Comment: do you have root access to your device?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: You can download a root checker from the play store, if the device is yours and you haven't rooted it then the answer is probably no, in which case, as far as I am aware, you need root access to access the contents of the data\data folder, However post your code as it could be your db isnt getting created

Comment: I know it gets created because I made Log msgs. In conclusion, you say that I can't get access to the database files if I'm not connecting with a device(which is not an emulator)?

Comment: Ok, well without seeing your code I can't really help, if you need to see the contents of a table then just do a select * and dump the output to a listview etc

Comment: I want to use an emulator and open it from the adm, I didn't understant what is a non-rooted device?

Comment: Dont worry about rooted as you are not using a real device.